# WPF : How to animate element width whenever it changes

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, width, element

This should be easy but I'm blanking out here.

I have a `TextBlock` inside of a `Border` control. The `Width` of the `Border` changes based on the length of the text in the `TextBlock` (updated in ViewModel). I would like this change in `Width` to be animated so that the width grows slowly (instead of jerky).

My Xaml:

```
<Border x:Name="myBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Some Text"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: can you please show the Xaml that contains the Border and TextBlock

Comment: `<Border x:Name="myBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="Some Text"/>
     </Border>`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting...

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect job for Expression Blend. You will need to create a `Storyboard` animation. Then once its created go into the code behind in visual studios and play it. You can tell it to play to a certain point based on how much text you have in your text block.

Here is a basic tutorial
http://www.silverlightbuzz.com/2009/10/12/animating-with-storyboards-in-blend/

This example has back end code also
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/wpf-storyboard-%E2%80%93-what-it-and

Comment: I guess what I would really like to know is how to animate when both the starting width and ending width are unknown. I want it to always animate anytime the width changes (irrespective of the current value).

Comment: Assume the starting width value is 0. Create a storyboard animation that expands the width of the textblock from 0-X and then when the TB is loaded set the start point of the Animation where you need it to be. The tutorials I posted will describe this process.

Comment: Why do you need Expression Blend, you can just write animations in VS, seems a bit odd to tell a user that they should to install another application do do a simple task like StoryBoards

Comment: Animation in visual studios is like attempting to bake a 3 layer cake in an easy bake oven. Expression blend is a free tool and is made for this specific thing. You can create this exact storyboard in less than 2 min. To someone that obviously isn't aware of storyboarding, why would you give him the most difficult path when there is a free easy tool to use.

Comment: If you define the visual states for the two points you can then use FluidLayout to automagically make smooth transitions. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2010/03/16/dynamic-layout-and-transitions-in-expression-blend-4.aspx

Comment: I had read this tutorial before indeed (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2010/03/16/dynamic-layout-and-transitions-in-expression-blend-4.aspx). I think that's gonna put me on the correct path. I'll take another look. Sorry if I lead you to believe that I'm a male or that I'm unfamiliar with Blend, Storyboards etc. It's just been a while since I've looked at it.